# Rails fragment caching of collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, caching, shopify, russian-doll-caching

I have a rails 4.1 app, that on a particular page retrieves a list of orders and lists them out in a table. It's important to note that the list is different depending on the logged in user.

To improve performance of this, I am looking to cache the partials for each order row. I am considering to do it like this:

**_order_list.html.erb**

```
<% cache(@orders) do %>
    <%= render @orders %>
  <% end %>
```

**_order.html.erb**

```
<% cache(order) do %>
  ...view code for order here
<% end %>
```

However, I'm unsure about the caching of the collection (@orders). Will all users then be served the same set of cached @orders (which is not desired)?

In other words, how can I ensure to cache the entire collection of @orders for each user individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will all users then be served the same set of cached @orders (which is
>   not desired)?

Actually `cache_digests` does not cache `@orders` themselves. It caches `html` part of the page for a particular given object or set of objects (e.g. `@orders`). Each time a user asks for a webpage, `@orders` variable is going to be set in controller action and its `digest` is compared to the cached digest.

So, assuming we retrieve `@orders` like this:

```
def index
  @orders = Order.where(:id => [1,20,34]).all
end
```

What we gonna get is cached view with a stamp like that:

> views/orders/**1**-20131202075718784548000/orders/**20**-20131220073309890261000/orders/**34**-20131223112753448151000/6da080fdcd3e2af29fab811488a953d0

Note that `ids` of retrieved orders are mentioned in that stamp, so each user with his/her own unique set of orders should obtain his/her own individual cached view.

But here comes some great downsides of your approach:

1. Page caches are always stored on disk. That means that you can't have page stamp with any desired length. As soon as you retrieve a solid bunch of orders in a time, you exceed your OS's limit for filenames (e.g. it's 255 bytes for linux) and end up with runtime error.
2. Orders are dynamic content. As soon as **at least one** of them updates, your cache becomes invalid. Cache generation and saving it to disk is a pretty consuming operation, so it would be better to cache *each order individually*. In this case you will have to re-generate cache for a single order instead of re-generating the whole massive collection's cache.